# Why isn't my if statement in my java game working?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am creating a modern version of breakout for PC in Java 7, but I have ran into a major problem that I can't seem to fix.

Why won't my `if` statement execute in this, even if the spacebar is pressed , lives IS greater than 0,  and the y coord of the ball is greater than 600?

I already tested this with a lot of print statements and log files, but nothing seems to work.

```
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  import java.awt.*;
  //import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

  public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable , KeyListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Graphics dbg;
private Image dbi;

int level = 0;
int lives = 6;
int powerup = 0;
int blocksGone = 0;
int vy = 0;
int vx = 0;
int by = 640;
int bx = 0;
int[] powerups = new int[8];

ImageIcon i0 = new ImageIcon("paddle.gif");
ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("sidebar.gif");
ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("laserpaddle.gif");
ImageIcon i3 = new ImageIcon("paddleCannon.gif");
ImageIcon i4 = new ImageIcon("laser.gif");
ImageIcon i5 = new ImageIcon("bullet.gif");
ImageIcon i6 = new ImageIcon("lifeIcon.gif");
ImageIcon i7 = new ImageIcon("ball.png");
ImageIcon i8 = new ImageIcon("bomb.png");
ImageIcon i9 = new ImageIcon("atomic.png");
//ImageIcon i10 = new ImageIcon("bullet.gif");

Image paddle;
Image side;
Image bullet;
Image bomb;
Image ball;
Image atomc;
Image life;
Image dead;

int paddlex = 400;
int pdx = 0;


public Game() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Breakout Smash");
    setSize(1024,560);
    setResizable(false);

    this.addKeyListener(this);

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        init();

        while (true) {

            move();
            Thread.sleep(5);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println ("java.lang.Execption in line 25, class Game. Stacktrace:");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    paddle = i0.getImage();
    side = i1.getImage();
    ball = i7.getImage();

}

public void paint (Graphics g) {

    dbi = createImage (getWidth(),getHeight());
    dbg = dbi.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbi , 0 , 0 , this);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    g.drawImage(side, this.getWidth() - side.getWidth(null), 0, null);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.drawString("Score", 950, 50);
    g.drawString("Lives: " + lives , 880, 50);
    g.drawImage(paddle, paddlex, 520, null);

    g.drawImage(ball, bx, by, null);

    repaint();

}

public void move () {

    //if (by <= getHeight()) {

    if (paddlex > 0 && paddlex < getWidth() - side.getWidth(null) - 50) {

        paddlex += pdx;

    } if (paddlex >= getWidth() - side.getWidth(null) - 50) {

        paddlex-= 2;

    } if (paddlex <= 0) {

        paddlex++;

    }

    if (bx > 0 && bx < getWidth() - side.getWidth(null) && by > 10 && by < getHeight()) {

        bx += vx;
        by -= vy;

    } if (by > 560) {

        by = 575;

        bx = 0;

    } if (bx < 5) {

        bx += 3;
        vx = vx * -1;

    } if (bx > getWidth() - side.getWidth(null) - 5) {

        bx -= 3;
        vx = vx * -1;

    } if (by < 15) {

        by++;
        vy = vy * -1;

    } if (by >= 515 && by <= 515 + paddle.getHeight(null) && bx + 8 > paddlex && bx + 8 < paddlex + paddle.getWidth(null)) {

        vy = vy * -1;
        vy ++;
        vx *= pdx;

        /*if (pdx == -2) {

            vx = vx * -2;

        }

        if (pdx == 2) {

            vx = vx * 2;

        }*/

    }

    //} else {

        //vy = 0;
        //vx = 0;

    //}

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {

        int quit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Quit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (quit  == 0) System.exit(0);

    }

    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

        pdx = -2;

    }

    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

        pdx = 2;

    }       
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

        pdx = 0;

    }

    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

        pdx = 0;

    }

    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

        //if (by > 600 && lives >= 0) { // this is my problem here

            lives--;

            vy = 1;
            vx = pdx;

            bx = paddlex + 10;
            by = 500;

            System.out.println ("Space hit!");

            /*if (lives == 0) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over!" , "!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            }

        }   */      

    }

}

 }
```

There must be something I'm not seeing in my code. The big question is: Why won't the ball respawn on the spacebar press and subtract one life at the same time?

Comment: You can add some debug info to understand which part of the if statement is wrong.

Comment: I once had to use keyChar instead of keyCode. Maybe that's your issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thank you for suggesting test cases, this solved quite a few minor problems already, I hope it works with my major problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
System.out.println("by:"+by+"   lives:"+lives);
```

before the if.

cases:

```
if(you dont see anything in the console){
     something is wrong with the way you get the input
}
else if(the value of `by` OR `lives` are not correct){
     search somewhere else in your code where you are changing the by and lives
}
```